# Is there any specific feature of softDelete in Prisma ORM?

Tags: orm, prisma, prisma-orm

I want to delete my record (softDelete) something like in typeorm it is softDelete() method.
I want the same thing in prisma.

I have seen in documentations there is a flag for deletion which is initially true/false, and we have to check it manually, but in other ORMs it is something like softDelete() method or something like that. I want that same functionality like on calling this this method deletedAt column will fill automatically and this record will not see or search by id but present virtually on database.

If anyone have idea to do that please tell me i stuck at that point from last week.

Comment: There is literally this exact scenario explained in Prisma's documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/client-extensions/middleware/soft-delete-middleware

You don't even have to implement a solution this fancy. You can add a `deleted` boolean field on your model (default value: `false`) and instead of deleting, you would update the record `deleted: true`. Sure, this causes some overhead as it requires you to filter out deleted records in every query.

Comment: Ok i have read that but looking for better option, i will try this .  Thank you....